# How to receive two strings from Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this class, I try to change rating. I should recieve two variables, but I can't do it. Check my `ChildChanged` listener, the error is somewhere near it.

This is my database:

[image: Here my database]

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private Button btn;
String TAG = "first";
 float r,n,r1,r2,rat; String LEC_ID = "5058586";

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    //mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);


    final RatingBar rBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rBar);
    rBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                    boolean fromUser) {
            r1 = rBar.getNumStars();
            //r1=rating;
            mDatabase = database.getReference();
            mDatabase.child(LEC_ID).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
            rat = (rating+r)/n;
            rBar.setRating(rat);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "рейтинг: " + String.valueOf(rating)+" "+r,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mDatabase.child(LEC_ID).child("n").setValue(n);
            mDatabase.child(LEC_ID).child("r").setValue(r2);
        }
    });
}

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Float>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Float>>() {}; //here it crashes
        Map<String, Float> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator );
        n = map.get("n")+1;
        r = map.get("r");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
 }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Also: "can't do it" is rather broad. What is the problem with the current code?